# Can you make a ref not change after context change? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a component that is a context consumer and changes text content based on context changes caused by swiping.

I thought that the best way to handle that would have been to extract swiping logic (attaching listeners and setting context based on results of swiping) into a custom hook and then call that hook with a ref to the swiping target set in useEffect.

```
const [node, setNode] = useState();

const ref = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    setNode(ref.current);
  }, []);

useSwiping(node); // custom hook

return (
<section ref={ref}>
      <h1>
        {text content provided by context}
      </h1>
</section>
);
```

The problem I'm facing is that the context changes enforce re-renders which creates new refs and cause my hook to get called with a new ref every time I want the text inside the swiping target to change.

Is there a way to make this work without removing and re-adding listeners every time context changes?

Comment: Can you try providing the condition as a second argument to useEffect() as in when you want it to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) to get rid of the ref:

```
const [node, setNode] = useState();

useSwiping(node); // custom hook

return (
  <section ref={ref => setNode(ref)}>

  </section>
);
```

Then inside the custom hook, `useEffect` to add the handlers:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if(ref) {
     //...
   }
 }, [ref]);
```

Comment: Still calls the custom hook after context changes. It looks much cleaner though.

Comment: Yes sure. That's how React works. Your custom hook should use `useEffect` then.

Comment: If you want to append the `ref` just once you can use a `ternary operator` like this:
`ref={ref => !node ? setRef(ref) : null}`

Comment: The ternary operator causes an infinite loop because at the start !node evaluates to true from useState() and there is no ref yet to set it to. The useEffect in custom hook seems to be the answer after a couple changes in the hook. I even tried it once before writing this question but I left the dependency array empty thinking it is only for changes, but it checks it the first time too. Thanks for the help!